# Rendering event data with fullcalendar in Zend Framework 2

Tags: javascript, php, json

Integrated fullcalendar with zf2...but not able to display the entered event in calender view

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        editable: true,
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        events: "show-events",

Comment: this is the js age that is view page particular code

Comment: my controller action code as below....(it is not correct)

Comment: public function showEventsAction() { 
       
        $date = $this->HolidaysTable->getHoliday(); 
        $responseData = array('title'=>$date->title,'url'=>$date->url,'start'=>$date->date);
        //$jsonencoded = \Zend\Json\Json::encode($responseData);
        return $responseData;
      
       
    }

Comment: Please edit your question with your code.